# Possibilities for dimensions of $\mathfrak{m}^i/\mathfrak{m}^{i+1}$ for a local ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, local-rings

Let $R$ be a local commutative ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, and denote by $k$ the residue field $R/\mathfrak{m}$. Then we can look at the sequence of $k$-vectorspaces
$$R/\mathfrak{m}, \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2, \mathfrak{m}^2/\mathfrak{m}^3, \mathfrak{m}^3/\mathfrak{m}^4 \ldots$$
This gives rise to a sequence of dimensions $(\dim_k \mathfrak{m}^i/\mathfrak{m}^{i+1})_{i\geq0}$ (we say $\mathfrak{m}^0=R$). For example, if $R=\mathbb{Z}_p$, the ring of $p$-adic integers, then the sequence is identically $1$.

> **Question1**: What (kind of) sequences can we acquire?

My motivation for this question is that I am looking at groups that act on rooted trees that are constructed from local rings, in a way that all nodes at distance $i$ from the root have the same degree, namely $\left|\mathfrak{m}^i/\mathfrak{m}^{i+1}\right|+1$. If the given sequence has distinct patterns (or distinct lack of patterns), this will imply extra symmetry (or lack of symmetry) in my tree.

Comment: You probably assume that $R$ is noetherian, so that $M$ is finitely generated. Although $M$ f.g. does not imply $R$ noetherian even if $\bigcap M^n=0$, we can assume with no restriction that $R$ is noetherian, since taking the completion yields a noetherian ring with the same sequence of dimensions.

Comment: For noetherian local rings, the study of such sequences is standard, check "Hilbert series" and "hilbert polynomial": the dimension of $M^i/M^{i+1}$ is known to coincide with a polynomial for $i$ large enough, whose degree is the Krull dimension of $R$.

Comment: I actually don't intend to assume this generally, though a lot of the examples I'll be studying will be noetherian. I'm trying to get a grip on how general I can take my local rings, and to what extent the possibly stranger, non-noetherian cases would be interesting.

Comment: what I explained is that either you can can assume the ring to be noetherian (possibly modifying the ring but not the sequence of dimensions), or you have $dim(M/M^2)=\infty$... are you really interested in the latter case?

Comment: I am unsure whether or not I will be able to keep working with the completely general case. The possibility that some of those dimensions would be infinite is, at this point, not a problem. In that case, I'm interested in what the rest of the tree would look like.

Comment: could you at least provide one example of interest for which $dim(M/M^2)=\infty$ and $\dim(M^i/M^{i+1})<\infty$ for some $i$? Of course you can have $M^i=0$ for some $i$ or some simple variations, but I'm wondering what you are looking for. I'm tempted to believe that, anyway, there exists a subring of $R$ for which $M$ is finitely generated and the values of $dim(M^i/M^{i+1})$ are the same for large $i$.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know any such examples, that is the kind of thing I am looking for (the non-noetherian examples I know of are indeed fairly easy, when looking at the dimensions, infinite or zero).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yves Cornulier's suggestion about the values of $\dim(M^i/M^{i+1})$ is correct. Either they are all infinite or there is a finitely generated local ring $(S,N)$ such that for large $i$, $ \dim(M^i/M^{i+1})=\dim(N^i/N^{i+1})$.

**Claim 1**: If $\dim(M^k/M^{k+1})<\infty$ for some $k$, then $\dim(M^l/M^{l+1})<\infty$ for all $l\geq k$.

If $\dim(M^k/M^{k+1})<\infty$ then there exist $a_1,\dots, a_n\in M^k$ s.t. $$M^k=\langle a_1,\dots, a_n\rangle +M^{k+1}.$$
We can assume that each $a_i$ is a product $a_{i,1}a_{i,2}\cdots a_{i,k}$ where $a_{i,j}\in M$. (Replace an $a_i$ by its summands).

Then
$$M^{k+1} =\langle s_1s_2\cdots s_{k+1} \mid s_i \in M\rangle \\
=\langle s a_i \mid s\in M, i=1,\dots,n\rangle + M^{k+2} \\
\subseteq \langle (sa_{i,1}\cdots a_{i,k-1})a_{j,k}\mid s\in M, i,j=1,\dots,n\rangle + M^{k+2} \\
\subseteq M^k\cdot \langle a_{j,k}\mid j=1,\dots,n\rangle + M^{k+2} \\
=\langle a_ia_{j,k}\mid i,j=1,\dots,n\rangle + M^{k+2}
$$
Hence, $M^{k+1}/M^{k+2}$ is finite dimensional.

**Claim 2:** For large $l$, $\dim(M^l/M^{l+1})$ equals the corresponding dimensions in a finitely generated local ring.

From the proof above one also sees that if one takes $N=\langle a_{i,j} \mid i=1,\dots, n, j=1,\dots k\rangle$, then
$M^l/M^{l+1}$ is generated by (residue classes of) elements in $N^l$ for all $l\geq k$.
Let 
$$S:=R/M \oplus N/(M^2\cap N)\oplus N^2/(M^3\cap N^2)\oplus \cdots$$
Then $S$ is a finitely generated subring of the associated graded ring of $R$, and the dimension of $N^l/(M^{l+1}\cap N^l)$ is equal to the dimension of $M^l/M^{l+1}$ for all $l\geq k$.

Comment: Thanks! To summarize: the sequence will always have the shape provided by the Hilbert Polynomial, with exception of possibly starting with a (possibly infinite) amount of infinity values? Your argument at least seems to give that only this is possible.

To show that all of these can occur, I guess one could start with a local ring $(R,M)$ with the desired sequence, and add some indeterminates to make the appropriate dimensions infinite (meaning that you'd have to divide out some multiples of those indeterminates to make it finite at some point, and preserve the values afterwards).

Comment: That's exactly what it means.